# ActivityForResult from Widget

Tags: android

I have a button in my main activity (act1) and in a widget. That button starts a different activity (act2).

In act1, I start act2 by doing startActivityForResult. When it's done, I handle it with onActivityResult.

However, in the widget, I start act2 by using a PendingIntent. When act2 is finished, it returns to act1 but does not trigger onActivityResult.

How do I make it hit onActivityResult when it returns to act1 or at least find out if act2 was started by the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make it hit onActivityResult when it returns to act1

You don't. "act1" will only be called with `onActivityResult(`) if it called `startActivityForResult()`.

> at least find out if act2 was started by the widget?

Put something in the `Intent` (e.g., custom action string or an extra) to differentiate the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with the same thing, and after trying a few approaches that did not work, wound up (1) as above, doing a putExtra on the PendingIntent to show that it was from the widget, (2) having the act2 Activity check the intent to see whether it was from the widget, and, if so, saving the setResult info to SharedPreferences as well, and (3) having the act1 Activity check SharedPreferences (in addition to the onActivityResult code for when act1 had launched act2 via startActivityForResult rather than just having been added to the backstack by the PendingIntent).